# How to describe the dishes served in char-grilled style at a Japanese restaurant?

Tags: expressions, alimentation

I took my colleague to a Japanese restaurant and wanted to give her a brief description of the dishes (mainly seafood) served there in char-grilled style. {in the middle in the attached pictures}

> cuit/grillé **au feu de bois**

I'm not sure if this phrase fits the bill, as it, to my mind, evokes the image of pizza in an enclosed wood oven, for instance. I wonder what are some idiomatic phrasings to describe this so that your interlocutor can accurately visualise how dishes are prepared?

[image]

[image]

Comment: @onvousaouï Malheureusement, ni *teppanyaki* ni *hibachi* ne s’en rapproche. Je viens d’ajouter une autre photo prise au moment où un chef était en train de préparer du saumon grillé.

Comment: Is that you taking the close-up of the wine label? If so I hope you can work it into one of your future questions! Anyway, if neither *teppanyaki* nor *hibachi* describe it in Japanese, could it be either *yakimono* or *yakiniku*?  If so, then [*grillade*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9NguDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT150&lpg=PT150&dq=yakimono+grillade&source=bl&ots=hQlOQEjlsv&sig=VlxC3yOYiXyp-RpULbmJmHqRAgY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRu7r57fPXAhUo0YMKHSz3DRQQ6AEIRTAH#v=onepage&q=yakimono%20grillade&f=false) proposed by @onvousaouï would be spot-on. If not, then please tell us what it's called in Japanese!

Comment: @PapaPoule Yes, I was taking a shot of the wine bottle,  with grilled salmon in the background by chance. Is there something particular that attracts your attention on the label? In Japanese, *sumibiyaki* is closer in meaning than *yakimono*.

Comment: Nothing in particular** ... I just figured that if it was worth a close-up, it must've been good and might have a story to tell or at least inspire a question! **Tiens, I am curious to know if this particular bottle had one of those "Contains Sulfides" warnings on the back like they do here in the US? I ask about this particular bottle because the Schu/e/llers are known for producing nice wines without having to resort (automatically) to adding sulfur.

Comment: @PapaPoule The chef recommended this particular wine to us for being hard to come by in Japan and an excellent match with the type of dishes we had that night. But for details beyond that, I may not be the best person around to discuss wines with! She loves taking photos for Instagram, so I was going along for the ride. I have recently noticed on many separate occasions that some Japanese-related things are not easy to explain in French. Sometimes it would be better to let photos do all the talking. :D

Answer (score 3):

On a indiqué qu'il ne s'agissait pas de cuisson sur plaque d'acier inoxydable ([*teppan table*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=18059390)) ni exactement d'un [*hibachi*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17033775) comme tel, et ça ne correspond pas à ma conception de faire rôtir sur la [broche](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/broche/0) de plus gros quartiers de viandes ; en Amérique du Nord c'est peut-être une forme de [*barbecue japonais*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakiniku). Il s'agit probablement en général de [*grillades*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8358689) ([japonaises](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuisine_japonaise)) (*mettre à la [grillade](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/grillade), grillade de*, et par métonymie la *viande grillée* ainsi cuite) parfois cuites *à la/en* petites ([brochettes](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/brochette/1)), donc par métonymie aussi des petites *brochettes*, cuites sur le [*gril*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=18054984), cuites *à feu vif* ; dans certains cas ce pourrait être sur des *braises ardentes*, voire sur [*charbon de bois*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/charbon/14715/locution?q=charbon%20de%20bois#152340), d'érable par exemple, ou autrement (*élément chauffant* etc.)...

Comment: Cette cuisinière à charbon personnalisée sur la photo n’a-t-elle rien à voir avec l’idée que tu t’en ferais en entendant « grillé au feu de bois » ?
 En fait, je m’en suis remis à la première et seule expression qui me soit venu à l'esprit à ce moment-là. Histoire d’être ne serait-ce qu’un tout petit peu compréhensible. :) Je m'égare du sujet, mais ça m’a pris un an et demi pour me rendre compte qu’il y a une étiquette *alimentation*.  :D

Comment: @Alone-zee Je n'emploierais pas la prép. _à_ avec feu/grillé comme dans _grillé au feu_, inusité, comme une forme imprécise de rôtir, et jeter _au feu_ ce serait détruire, pas cuire. Plutôt _sur charbon de bois, (le) gril_, avec au, bien _au chalumeau/bbq_... P.-ê. que _au feu de bois_ fait penser à _au four à bois_ et donc à pizza... En résumé à mon avis le choix de prép. ; ensuite le substantif grillade supérieur au participe passé _grillé_ à mon avis sauf si on veut parler de la _viande grillée_ et insérer un adjectif  (marinée à ... par exemple etc.). Mais ça reste cuit sur le gril...Merci

Comment: @Alone-zee ref. _alimentation_, c'est qu'il a un synonyme _cuisine/cooking_ et j'ai déjà écrit qq. questions sur le sujet, comme sur le fameux _court-bouillon_, donc je me souviens. Oui ce peut être utile de jeter un coup d’œil à la vue [_Tags_](https://french.stackexchange.com/tags) qu'on regarde trop peu souvent. Ça peut donner des idées sur certains angles pour des questions etc. Merci !

Answer (score 3):

Les photos montrent de petites flammes qui consument lentement le bois "à l'étouffée" et le transforment en braises.

Le foyer à la forme des autels sacrificiels des hindous ou à celui qu'Homère évoque quand Ulysse est à la porte des Enfers (un trou cubique dans la terre dont les arêtes sont de la longueur d'une épée).

Contrairement au feu de la forge avivé par le soufflet, peu d'air alimente le foyer quand l'âtre est enterré, le charbon de bois se fabrique lentement sous nos yeux, les braises rayonnent, entretiennent la combustion du bois et s'enfoncent peu à peu dans les cendres.

Quand il y a suffisamment de charbons rougeoyants le cuisinier sacrificateur peut faire l'offrande de la nourriture dont les parfums vont nourrir les narines des dieux olympiens, et les aliments... les clients.

Et sur la carte, il mentionne ***cuisson à la braise***.